# How to get all flash messages in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a number of fields that have numerous validations from codeigniter validations. but now its showing one single validation error flash that is truly validated message

**Here is my controller block code**

```
public function customer_upd()
{
    extract($_POST);
    $err = '';

    $date1 = $_POST['cust_upd_bd'];
    $date2 = $_POST['cust_upd_dom'];

    if($date2 != "") {
        $datediff = (strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
        $res = floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
        if ($res == " ") {
            $err .= "Please Enter a Date";
        } elseif ($res < 365) {
            $err .= "Child marriage is prohibited";
        }
        if ($err != '') {
            $_SESSION['dateerror'] = $err;
            redirect('customer/edit/'.$_POST['ctmr_upd_id']);
        }
    }
    $original_value1 = $this->db->query("SELECT customer_email FROM customer WHERE id = ".$_POST['ctmr_upd_id'])->row()->customer_email ;
    if($_POST['cust_upd_email'] != $original_value1) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('add_failed','Email id must be unique & valid email address.');
        $is_unique =  '|is_unique[customer.customer_email]';
    } else {
        $is_unique =  '';
    }
    $original_value2 = $this->db->query("SELECT customer_mobile FROM customer WHERE id = ".$_POST['ctmr_upd_id'])->row()->customer_mobile ;
    if($_POST['cust_upd_mobile'] != $original_value2) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('add_failed','Mobile no must be unique & exact 10 digit numeric length. ');
        $is_phoneunique =  '|is_unique[customer.customer_mobile]';
    } else {
        $is_phoneunique =  '';
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cust_upd_email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|trim'.$is_unique);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cust_upd_mobile', 'Mobile', 'required|exact_length[10]|is_natural|trim'.$is_phoneunique);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cust_upd_name', 'Customer name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|callback_customAlpha');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('cust','The Customer field must be at least 3 characters in length. ');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cust_upd_bd', 'Date of birth', 'regex_match[(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cust_upd_dom', 'Date of marriage', 'regex_match[(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() ) {
        $userdata = $this->session->userdata();
        $userId = $userdata['id'];
        if (!$userId):
            redirect(site_url());
        endif;

        extract($_POST);
        print_r($_POST); exit;
        $data = array(
            'customer_name' => ucwords($_POST['cust_upd_name']),
            'birth_date' => $_POST['cust_upd_bd'],
            'anniversery_date' => $_POST['cust_upd_dom'],
            'customer_mobile' => $_POST['cust_upd_mobile'],
            'customer_email' => $_POST['cust_upd_email'],
            'status' => $_POST['cust_upd_status'],
            'address' => $_POST['ctmr_address'],
            'cat_type' => $_POST['file_cat']
        );
        $userdata = $this->session->userdata();
        $userId = $userdata['id'];
        $this->db->where('user_id', $userId);
        $this->db->where('id', $_POST['file_cat']);
        $this->db->where('cat_status', 'Enable');
        $get_file = $this->db->get('category');
        $res_file = $get_file->num_rows();

        if($res_file >0){
            $userdata = $this->session->userdata();
            $userId = $userdata['id'];
            $this->db->where('user_id', $userId);
            $this->db->where('id', $_POST['ctmr_upd_id']);
            $ctmr_upd = $this->db->update('customer', $data);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('edit_failed','Something went wrong.');
            redirect('customer/edit/'.$_POST['ctmr_upd_id']);
        }
        redirect(site_url() . '/customer');
    } else {
        redirect('customer/edit/'.$_POST['ctmr_upd_id']);
    }
}
```

**And here is my view code**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <?php if($error = $this->session->flashdata('add_failed')): ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger  col-md-offset-4">
                            <?php echo $error; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($error1 = $this->session->flashdata('edit_failed')): ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger  col-md-offset-4">
                            <?php echo $error1; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($error2 = $this->session->flashdata('cust')): ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger  col-md-offset-4">
                            <?php echo $error2; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($_SESSION['dateerror']){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger col-sm-7 col-md-offset-3" role="alert">'.$_SESSION['dateerror'].'</div>';
                unset($_SESSION['dateerror']);
            }
            ?>
```

**And here is a snap**

[image]

Whenever i tries to submit with their validate data, its showing this above error flash message.

i tried many times but unable to achieve any success.

Please guide me and tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: With in your only one flash message is set which is `$this->session->set_flashdata('edit_failed','Something went wrong.');`

Comment: but buddy. how can i fix it?

Comment: Use condition like if($this->session->flashdata('edit_failed')) {  echo $this->session->flashdata('edit_failed')  }

Comment: it showing only one single error flash message every time but name field value is ok

Comment: its previously done with it...!

Comment: You are using same div to show message at top may be they are overriding. Show them at bottom of respective field. Why dont you use jquery or CI validations instead of putting them in session

Comment: i have used jquery for validation but it also needed servers side validation..

Comment: For server side you can use codeigniter validations. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: i already know about it brother. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned code to retrieve all flashdata.

```
$this->session->flashdata();
```

It will return array with all flashdata, simply omit the key parameter.

Let me know if it not works.